# Display images as id wise in section in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uicollectionview, alamofire

[image: Please see now from my code I am getting only one image in all section]

I am creating horizontal collection view and collection view is inside the tableview cell everything works perfect in tableview but in collection view I can not able to display section wise let me show you my response

**Response**

```
{
    "subject_list" =     (
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 4;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 17;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1530600693.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = " 01. Measurement";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 23;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1451930609.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 24;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1884777188.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 25;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1518702048.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Physics;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 8;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 26;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1437196139.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = " 1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 8;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 27;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1903171865.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 8;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Chemistry;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 9;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 31;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1319333294.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 9;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Testing;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 10;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 28;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1373218664.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 10;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject";
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 11;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 29;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/246189282.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 11;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject 1";
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 12;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 30;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1342731807.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 12;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject 2";
        }
    );
```

I want to display sub_list images section wise but not show as per section let me show my code

**Code**

```
var urls = [String]()
struct SubjectResponse: Decodable {
    let subjectList: [Subject]
}

struct Subject: Decodable {
    let subList: [Chapter]
}

struct Chapter: Decodable {
    let chId : String
    let chImage: String
    let chName: String
    let conId: String
    let levelId: String
    let subId: String
}



   func callSubChapAPI(){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let studentlvl = "student_lvl"
        let student_lvl = preferences.object(forKey: studentlvl) as! String
        print(student_lvl)
        let params = ["level_id": student_lvl]
        Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseData() { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                   // self.subjects = try decoder.decode(SubjectResponse.self, from: data)



                    let subjects = try decoder.decode(SubjectResponse.self, from: data);                                       print(subjects)
                    var indexPath: IndexPath?


                        let url = subjects.subjectList[indexPath?.section ?? 0].subList[indexPath?.row ?? 0].chImage
                        print(url)
                        self.urls.append(url)



                    self.collView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ExploreTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return self.urls.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //let section1 = subjects?.subjectList[section]
        return urls[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell
      let imageUrl = URL(string: urls[indexPath.row])!
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo_grey"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
        //let name = subjects?.subjectList[indexPath.section].subList[indexPath.row].chName
        //cell.lblChapName.text = name
        return cell
    }
}
```

I want section wise images I hope you will understand what I mean to tell you and in any confusion then please ask in comment and please tell me what will be the solution for issue

Please check viewcontroller code

```
   func callSubChapAPI(){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let studentlvl = "student_lvl"
        let student_lvl = preferences.object(forKey: studentlvl) as! String
        print(student_lvl)
        let params = ["level_id": student_lvl]
        Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let value):

                let result = response.result

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let categorylist = dict["subject_list"]{
                        self.subList = categorylist as! [AnyObject]
                        print(self.subList)
                        self.tbllist.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        })
    }
```

**tableview methods**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ExploreTableViewCell
        let name = subList[indexPath.row]["sub_name"]
        cell.lblTitle.text = name as? String
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: please my question check i added screen shot

Comment: Your code structure is wrong, can you show me you main controller code and tableview delegates.

Comment: are you able to under stand which type of output i want?

Comment: you mean tableview delegate data source?

Comment: Yeah I understand your requirement. Show me tableview delegate (cellforrow) and where you calling the API?

Comment: please check i updated the code

Comment: You dealing the code in wrong way, wait let me show you correct path.

Comment: yes please show me thank you

Answer (score 1):

**1. Your UI hierarchy should be like this below image.**

[image]

2. In `MainController`, your tableView cells depends on your number of subjects (phy, chem, math etc)

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return subject_List.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ExploreTableViewCell

       cell.lblTitle.text = subject_List[indexPath.row]. sub_name
       cell.arrSubList = subject_List.sub_list
       return cell
   }
   ```
3. In `ExploreTableViewCell`

   ```
   class ExploreTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

       var arrSubList = [sub_list]() 

       func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
           return self.arrSubList.count

       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           //let section1 = subjects?.subjectList[section]
           return arrSubList.count
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell

           let aSubList = arrSubList[indexPath.row]

           let imageUrl = URL(string: aSubList.ch_image)!
           cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo_grey"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
           cell.lblChapName.text = aSubList.ch_name
           return cell
       }
   }
   ```

> Note :

May be you get datatype error or some other, just because I does not have proper model name and conventions that you are using.

From above you got basic idea about how maintain the complex structure easily in MVC. For any query you can further ask.

> Edit

1. **Your api structure**

[image]

2. **Array that you have to send in UITableViewCell**

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks i will try this and let you know if any query

Comment: @VishalParmar check note.

Comment: Ok i will note that

Comment: can you please tell me from where you get subject_List.sub_list at cellforrowat

Comment: i mean i am not able to understand which array you are passing to arrSubList which is in cell

Comment: please reply i am very confusing

Comment: @VishalParmar It is the array of dict that have `ch_name, ch_id, ch_name .... etc`. I am simply sending this array to the UITableViewCell so that I can parse it accordingly. Bcz collectionView data depends on this array.

Comment: yes but you mean i have to create struct for that ok?

Comment: you already have `Chapter`. In my above answer, I am assuming you properly able to bind your json data with Model. If your data is not properly binded then use any online tool -> eg. 1. [Quick type](https://app.quicktype.io/) 2.  [Json cafe](http://www.jsoncafe.com/) etc.